# Visual Studio Code Error message: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup

I am new to webscraping, and I want to use beautifulsoup in order to do so, but whenever I try to import `BeautifulSoup` from `bs4`, I get the error message in the title. I have pip installed `bs4` from my own terminal, as well as, on visual studio code, and still get the same error. It's like it can't find where bs4 is installed or something. If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Image of error here]

Comment: Pls. do pip list and check if that module is present there and run the import statement in the python terminal.

Comment: Once try restarting the terminal. Some packages need the terminal to be restart to reflect the newly install modules.

Comment: @Simplecode 
Image of my PIP list
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJUnm.png

Image of me importing BeautifulSoup in python terminal
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfJnZ.png

Works fine in python terminal, which is what confuses me on why it won't work in visual studio...is anything weird in the folder it is saved to maybe?

Comment: I think what steven has mentioned in the answer below might be the reason. Pls. select proper python interpreter in the project settings of visual studio

Answer (score 0):

The packages you installed into `python39` environment:

```
c:\users\austin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
```

But you execute the python file with `python in WindowsApp` environment:

```
c:\users\austin\appdata\local\microsoft\windowsApps\pythonSoftwareFoundation.python.3.9_abz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
```

So, you need to switch to the global python environment (If you don't know how to switch the environment, you can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)). But it's recommended to create a virtual environment (refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment)).